# How can I reliably take away the new lines in a javascript string?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove the new lines in a javascript string.
http://jsfiddle.net/muT5V/

However, the alert box produced from this code (jQuery is included) still retains the new lines.

My javascript:

```
var s = $('#aDivWithContent').html();
s = s.replace('\n', '').replace('\s', '');
alert(s);​
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="aDivWithContent">
    <ul>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>baz</li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

Why?

Comment: You probably have to escape the backslash with another backslash if you want to define your regexes as literal strings.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this works either: http://jsfiddle.net/muT5V/4/ What is an alternative definition of strings? Raw strings?

Comment: I believe there is another syntax that looks like this:  someString.replace(/\n/g, '');

Comment: Like Zuum said, you also have to pass it the "g" flag, which means replace all occurrences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
s = s.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t|\s)/gm,"");
```

Comment: Please note that the \s will remove all spaces so if you had "foo bar", it would become "foobar"

Answer (score 2):

You need RegExp with g option and \r cleanup

var r = new RegExp("\r", "g");

var n = new RegExp("\n", "g");

str = str.replace(r,'').replace(n,'');

Answer (score 0):

The Reason is, that replace() only replaces ONE found.
If you use a RegEx as first parameter from replace(), then all found results will be replaced.

```
var s = $('#aDivWithContent').html();
s = s.replace(new RegExp("\n", "g"), 'a');
s = s.replace(new RegExp("\s", "g"), 'b');

alert(s);
```